# How do I remove a picture from a post permanently?

Tags: discussion, editing

Is it possible to remove an uploaded picture permanently without deleting the entire answer? I uploaded a picture of a dead mouse on [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/theres-a-mouse-in-my-house) without considering it may be offensive to other users. I removed it at request, but it's still there in the revision history. Is the only way around this to delete the answer and re-post it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you delete the answer it will be still visible to mods and those with access to the tools menu.

I think the fact that you edited out of the answer should be OK in this case. Someone would have to go looking at the revision history to find it.